# Vuex Axios Token Undefined

Tags: vue.js, django-rest-framework, axios, vuex

I am trying to perform user login with Vuejs and Django. I use vuex and django restframework as a component. When I use the user login form with Vuex store, django creates token for the user. However, vue js does not detect the generated user token. token is returning as undefined.

My store.js codes

```
import Vue from 'vue'
import Vuex from 'vuex'
import axios from 'axios'

Vue.use(Vuex)

export default new Vuex.Store({
    state: {
        status: '',
        token: localStorage.getItem('token') || '',
        user : {}
    },
    mutations: {
        auth_request(state){
            state.status = 'loading'
        },
        auth_success(state, token, user){
            state.status = 'success'
            state.token = token
            state.user = user
        },
        auth_error(state){
            state.status = 'error'
        },
        logout(state){
            state.status = ''
            state.token = ''
        },
    },
    actions: {
        login({commit}, user){
            return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
                commit('auth_request')
                axios({url: 'http://localhost:8001/api/v1/token/create', data: user, method: 'POST' })
                .then(resp => {
                    const token = resp.data.token
                    const user = resp.data.user
                    localStorage.setItem('token', token)
                    // Add the following line:
                    axios.defaults.headers.common['Authorization'] = 'Bearer ${token}'
                    commit('auth_success', token, user)
                    resolve(resp)
                })
                .catch(err => {
                    commit('auth_error')
                    localStorage.removeItem('token')
                    reject(err)
                })
            })
        },
        register({commit}, user){
            return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
                commit('auth_request')
                axios({url: 'http://localhost:8001/api/v1/users/create', data: user, method: 'POST' })
                .then(resp => {
                    const token = resp.data.token
                    const user = resp.data.user
                    localStorage.setItem('token', token)
                    // Add the following line:
                    axios.defaults.headers.common['Authorization'] = 'Bearer ${token}'
                    commit('auth_success', token, user)
                    resolve(resp)
                })
                .catch(err => {
                    commit('auth_error', err)
                    localStorage.removeItem('token')
                    reject(err)
                })
            })
        },
        logout({commit}){
            return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
                commit('logout')
                localStorage.removeItem('token')
                delete axios.defaults.headers.common['Authorization']
                resolve()
            })
        }
    },
    getters : {
      isLoggedIn: state => !!state.token,
      authStatus: state => state.status,
    }
})
```

Main.js

```
...
import store from './store';
import Axios from 'axios';

Vue.prototype.$http = Axios;
const token = localStorage.getItem('token')
if (token) {
  Vue.prototype.$http.defaults.headers.common['Authorization'] = 'Bearer ' + token
}
...
```

Login page

```
...
  data() {
    return {
      username: '',
      password: ''
    }
  },
  methods: {
    login: function() {
      let username = this.username
      let password = this.password
      this.$store.dispatch('login', { username, password })
      .then(() => this.$router.push('/'))
      .catch(err => console.log(err))
    }
  }
...
```

Comment: What do you mean by "Vue does not detect the generated user token"? Are you confirming the token is in the login response? At what point after login are you reading the token in Vue?

Comment: Hi, did you figure this out? Having the same issue.

Comment: I have the same issue but not for the token but for the user.

Answer (score 1):

Your main.js runs before store.js. The token only be generated after you call login action in store.js. After that nothing trigger the `localStorage.getItem()` method again, so the token remains undefined there.

The easiest way to get token is put another entry in getters for token, then use mapGetters to get it from any component you want.

Answer (score 0):

If anyone else runs into it:

I have it calling some private helpers:

```
function setDefaultAuthHeaders(state) {
    axios.defaults.headers.common.Authorization = state.currentToken
       ? `Bearer ${state.currentToken.token}`
       : ''
}

function saveState(key, state) {
    window.localStorage.setItem(key, JSON.stringify(state))
}
```

Then, in my mutation I have something to call it:

```
export const mutations = {
    SET_TOKEN(state, newToken) {
        state.currentToken = newToken
        saveState('currentToken', newToken)
        setDefaultAuthHeaders(state)
    },
}
```